# How to Access a Method When using KeyListeners?

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, awt, keylistener

everyone! I want to do something with KeyListeners that cause the canvas to repaint whenever I press a button. However, the problem is that the KeyListener can't access any methods in the other classes because of encapsulation. What's the key to fixing this?

Thank you!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
public class FaceFrame extends JFrame {
    private FaceCanvas face;
    public FaceFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800, 800);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        KeyListenerTester bob = new KeyListenerTester();
        face = new FaceCanvas();
        face.addKeyListener(bob);
        add(face, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame faceFrame = new FaceFrame();
    }

}

class FaceCanvas extends Canvas { 
    private Face whiteGuy;
    private Face redGuy;
    public FaceCanvas() {
        setBackground( Color.BLUE);
        setSize( 800, 800 );

        whiteGuy = new Face(50, 50, 150, 150, Color.WHITE, "White");
        redGuy = new Face(300, 300, 150, 150, Color.RED, "Red");
    }
    public void paint( Graphics g ) { 
        // override paint method by re-defining it
        whiteGuy.paint(g);
        redGuy.paint(g);
        repaint();
    }
}

class Face {
    int xpos, ypos;
    int width, height;
    Color skinTone;
    String tattoo;
    Font f;
    public Face(int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, Color skinTone, String tattoo) {
        this.xpos = xpos;
        this.ypos = ypos;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.skinTone = skinTone;
        this.tattoo = tattoo;
        f = new Font( "Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC| Font.BOLD, 24 );
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor( skinTone );
        g.drawOval( xpos, ypos, width, height );
        g.drawLine( xpos+ 10, ypos+ height-30, xpos+ width-30, ypos + height- 30 );
        g.setFont(f);
        g.drawString( tattoo, xpos + 60, ypos + 20 );
    }

}

class KeyListenerTester extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

        JLabel label;

        public KeyListenerTester() {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the input. However, my problem is never really in understanding the logic behind it.

The issue is mainly from me not knowing how to actually code it properly.

Comment: The MultiListener example at the end of the page I linked to shows how to use an ActionListener defined in another class (if you really want to do that). Read it. Then substitute ActionListener with KeyListener.

Comment: It need not be defined as a separate class! I just don't know how to implement it otherwise. :( Thank you for the link! :)